# Sed. How to print lines matching pattern from another file?

Tags: sed, match, filenames

I have file1 containing some text, like:

```
abcdef 123456 abcdef
ghijkl 789123 abcdef
mnopqr 123456 abcdef
```

and I have file2 containing single line of text which I want to use as pattern:

```
ghijkl 789123
```

How can I use second file as a pattern to print lines containing it to third file using sed? like file3:

```
ghijkl 789123 abcdef
```

I've tried to use

```
sed -ne "s/r file2//p" file1 > file3
```

But the content of file3 is blank for some reason
P.S. using Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest sed solution on linux: `` sed -n /`<file2`/p file1 > file3 ``, but windows does not provides backticks. So the windows work-around would be:

```
set /p PATERN=<file2
sed -n /%PATERN%/p file1 > file3
```

Comment: That's even better! suits more for my script. You have my gratitude!

Answer (score 2):

If you have `sed`, do have access to `grep`?

```
grep -f file2 file1 > file3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` solution is:

```
    cat f2.txt | xargs -I {} sed -n "/{}/p" f1.txt > f3.txt
```

but, as @Cyrus correctly notes, `grep` is the proper tool for this solution and it's much nicer:

```
    grep -f f2.txt f1.txt > f3.txt
```

**Note**: using these incredibly powerful *nix tools like `sed`, `grep`, `cat`, `xargs`, `bash`, etc. on Microsoft Windows can be frustrating. Consider spinning up a Linux environment, instead -- you'll save yourself many hours of grief dealing with subtle path and environment issues from emulators like Cygwin, etc.

Comment: Was thinking the same thing about linux once I've posted it. Thanks for the sed solution, I think I'll need to get myself cat as well.